# Testing userDefaults and private function

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, nsuserdefaults

I'm using `Coordinator` pattern to handle ViewControllers.

In my `appCoordinator` I set `rootViewController` by users login state.

```
protocol Coordinatorbale {
    func coordinate()
}


class AppCoordinator: Coordinatorbale {
    init(){ .... }

    func coordinate() {
       let logedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "user_logged_in")

        if logedIn {
            window.rootViewController = V1
        else {
            window.rootViewController = V2
        }
    }

}
```

How can I test this?

If I take out the logic from the `coordinate` func.
The new fun will be private and then I still cant test the state.

```
private func setRootByUserState(logedIn: Bool) {
    if logedIn {
            window.rootViewController = V1
        else {
            window.rootViewController = V2
        }
}
```

So I'm stuck with a `private` method or a `UserDefaults`.

How can I Unit test this behavior?

Comment: Just to be sure, you're asking how to unit test this right?

Comment: @pbodsk yep, thanks i edited the question to make it clear

Comment: cool I thought so, so I went ahead and made an attempt at an answer :)

Comment: Why don't you set `true/false` value in `userdefaults` before calling the `cooridnate` method?

Comment: @kamaran changing userDefaults in test Target doesn't change userDefaults in app Target

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `UserDefaults` behind a protocol.

```
protocol PreferenceAware {
    var isLoggedIn: Bool { get set }
}
```

And then have another class conform to this `protocol`

```
struct UserDefaultsPreferences: PreferenceAware {
    private let userLoggedInKey = "user_logged_in"
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: userLoggedInKey)
    }

    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: userLoggedInKey)
    }
}
```

Your `AppDelegate` then has a variable of type `PreferenceAware` like so:

```
var prefenceContainer: PreferenceAware = UserDefaultsPreferences()
```

And you use that in your method like so

```
func coordinate() {
   let loggedIn = preferenceContainer.isLoggedIn

    if loggedIn {
        window.rootViewController = V1
    else {
        window.rootViewController = V2
    }
}
```

Now, for testing, you can create a test object that conforms to `PreferenceAware`, update your `preferenceContainer` in the `AppDelegate` and control it as you see fit.

```
struct MockPreferenceAware: PreferenceAware {
    var isLoggedIn: Bool
}
```

Allowing you to do something like this in your test:

```
func testLoggedIn() {
    let mock = MockPreferenceAware(isLoggedIn: true)
    appDelegate.preferenceContainer = mock

    //now you are sure of the path that your code will follow in the coordinate method
}
```

And you can also test the flow when the user is not logged in:

```
func testNotLoggedIn() {
    let mock = MockPreferenceAware(isLoggedIn: false)
    appDelegate.preferenceContainer = mock

    //now you are sure of the path that your code will follow in the coordinate method
}
```

Note, I'm not near a compiler at the moment (horrible thought right :)), so I haven't tested the above for syntax errors, but hopefully you get the idea, and hopefully this is useful to you.